# What is the best way to declare JSON structures like this in C#?

Tags: c#, json, object, dynamic, declaration

im porting a solution to C# code, that contains a piece of code like this.

```
public object data = 
{

    Background:
    [
        [1.45,2.85, 42.6,2.85, 42.6,44, 1.45,44]
    ]
    ,
    Wall1:
    [
        [8.35,7.05, 116.3,7.05, 116.3,938.8, 8.35,938.8]
    ]
    ,
    Wall2:
    [
        [0,0, 141,0, 141,455, 0,455]
    ]
    ,
    Floor:
    [
        [0.35,8.4, 1075.05,8.4, 1075.05,48.15, 0.35,48.15]
    ]
    .... a lot of other declaration..
```

What is the best way do declare this kind of object in c#??

Thanks..

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what exactly does the code do and how are you going to use it? Are the arrays supposed to be arrays of arrays? Should all of those arrays contain `double`s? Why are the numbers formatted as pairs, does that have some significance?

Comment: Yes.. Yes. it is basicaly string to double array...
Im porting from JavaScript to C# ... My only concern is that it is used in the code like this... :
data.Background[2] ;   Or something like this..

Comment: I can use the way data["Background"][2] .. but it will make necessary a lot of changes in the entire code. Is there a solutions that could make it accessible directaly like this. ?
    data.Background[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDictionary<string, object>` would fit your solution if the contents are not known in advance. If direct structure is known, you can create a strongly-typed class for it, which will be easier to maintain and less-error prone, with the benefit of performance gain.